# jMeter JSON parsing failing on CentOS

Tags: centos, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, taurus

I am running jMeter via Taurus (bzt) on CentOS.  My first call is a login that needs to get the access tokens from the returned JSON.  When I run this test on my Mac everything works as expected.  But when I run it on my CentOS server I get the following error every time I try to extract data from a JSON path.  I have tried reinstalling the plugin.  I have also tried running it directly via jMeter.  In both cases I still have the same problem.  Any idea what is causing this error?

> 2016/06/08 14:34:05 WARN  - com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor: Extract failed com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Extracted array is empty
>       at com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor.process(JSONPathExtractor.java:104)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:776)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:489)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) for quite a while it might be the case it's using previously downloaded JMeter 2.13 which doesn't have JSON Path PostProcessor yet. So the following commands can help:

1. Upgrade Taurus to the most recent version:

   ```
   sudo pip instal --upgrade bzt
   ```
2. Remove previous JMeter installation:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus
   ```
3. Run your test normally - Taurus should download JMeter 3.0

If you don't have possibility to upgrade JMeter and/or Taurus - use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) plugin instead

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem was a version mismatch. I downloaded the latest greatest (stable) jMeter when I started working with jMeter about a month ago.  About a week after I downloaded jMeter they released 3.0.  I didn’t start setting up my perf server until over a week later.  When I installed jMeter on the sever it got 3.0, but my Mac had 2.13.  So I was trying to run jmx files created with 2.13 on my 3.0 server.  I never got any version mismatch errors just stuff like I shared above.  After I upgraded my Mac and rewrote my jmx files via 3.0 everything worked fine.